# De donde se origina la expresion "echar aguas"?

Tags: etimología, méxico

En programas de television, y recientemente al interactuar con la gente en mi viaje a Mexico, vi que la expresión de "echar aguas" es muy popular, al parecer solo en la cultura mexicana. De donde se originó esta expresión que quiere decir "avisar" o algo similar?

ejemplos:

> Si ves que vienen los dueños de la casa, me echas aguas. *Aguas! Aguas! Allí vienen!*

Comment: En España también se dice

Comment: Nunca he oído la expresión en España. Lo único parecido que he oído es el uso de ¡Agua!¡Agua! en contextos criminales para advertir de la llegada de la policía.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En los tiempos medievales y un poco más adelante, no habían desagües y la gente echaba el agua hacia una zanja en medio de la calle o los que vivían en altos la tiraban por la ventana o balcón, estos últimos antes de lanzar los desechos gritaban `¡Agua!` para avisar  que iban a tirar desechos.

De ahí que para avisar a alguien se diga `¡echar aguas!` o `¡Aguas!`

Comment: En España, la expresión es *dar el agua*, pero suele usarse solo como aviso de que viene la policía entre delincuentes de poca monta (vendedores ilegales, trileros y demás).

Comment: La zanja en cuestión en medio de la calle se llamaba el arroyo, de donde salen expresiones como "estar en el arroyo".

Comment: @Envite esa frase del arroyo se usa en Cuba todavía, para indicar que uno esta mas atras que los cordales, sin un peso o en una situacion muy mala...lol

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina no se usa la expresión de esa manera. Pero, con el mismo origen que comenta Emilio en la otra respuesta, se usa ocasionalmente la expresión `...sin decir "agua va"` como sinónimo de `...sin avisar`.